# Converting nested list columns to one list for cohen's kappa in R

Tags: r, list, nested, cohen-kappa

I have a large dataset which includes three key elements. Each element is a list which contains nested data frames.  My aim is to able to prepare the data for a cohen's kappa analysis for each event (e.g. `auto_trig`, `double_trig`) which requires one long binary column of data. I have looked at many semi-similar examples on stack overflow to try and pivot the data into one long column but am yet to find one that works for my data set.

Extract of datasets `df` `df1`

```
df<- list(`9950892A_Events_5` = structure(list(Section = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 
69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 
85, 86), Epoch5 = c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 
111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 
241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 
371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 
501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 
631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 
761, 771, 781, 791, 801, 811, 821, 831, 841, 851), Epoch51 = c(11, 
21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 
161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 
291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 
421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 
551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 
681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791, 801, 
811, 821, 831, 841, 851, 861), auto_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), double_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), high_leak = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), hypopnea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    ineffective_eff = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -86L)), `9803659A_Events_150` = structure(list(
    Section = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
    30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
    45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
    60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
    75, 76, 77, 78, 79), Epoch5 = c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 
    71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 
    191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 
    311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 
    431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 
    551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 
    671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781
    ), Epoch51 = c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 
    121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 
    241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 
    361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 
    481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 
    601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 
    721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791), auto_trig = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L), double_trig = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), high_leak = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), hypopnea = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hypoventilation = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), mixed_apnea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), obstruct_apnea = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -79L
)),  `11099325A_Events_140` = structure(list(Section = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76), Epoch5 = c(1, 11, 21, 31, 
41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 
181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 
311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 
441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 
571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 
701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751), Epoch51 = c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 
61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 
191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 
321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 
451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 
581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 
711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761), double_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hypopnea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ineffective_eff = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-76L)))

df1<-list(`9950892B_Events_95` = structure(list(Section = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95), Epoch5 = c(1, 
11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 
151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 
281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 
411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 
541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 
671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791, 
801, 811, 821, 831, 841, 851, 861, 871, 881, 891, 901, 911, 921, 
931, 941), Epoch51 = c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 
111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 
241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 
371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 
501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 
631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 
761, 771, 781, 791, 801, 811, 821, 831, 841, 851, 861, 871, 881, 
891, 901, 911, 921, 931, 941, 951), auto_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), double_trig = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), high_leak = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hypopnea = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-95L)), `9803659B_Events_28` = structure(list(Section = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79), Epoch5 = c(1, 
11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 
151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 
281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 
411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 
541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 
671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781), 
    Epoch51 = c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 
    121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 
    241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 
    361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 
    481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 
    601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 
    721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791), apnea = c(0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), auto_trig = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), double_trig = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), high_leak = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hypopnea = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -79L
)), `9756190B_Events_68` = structure(list(Section = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 
69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 
85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98), Epoch5 = c(1, 
11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 
151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 
281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 
411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 
541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 
671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791, 
801, 811, 821, 831, 841, 851, 861, 871, 881, 891, 901, 911, 921, 
931, 941, 951, 961, 971), Epoch51 = c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 
71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 
201, 211, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 311, 321, 
331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 401, 411, 421, 431, 441, 451, 
461, 471, 481, 491, 501, 511, 521, 531, 541, 551, 561, 571, 581, 
591, 601, 611, 621, 631, 641, 651, 661, 671, 681, 691, 701, 711, 
721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 771, 781, 791, 801, 811, 821, 831, 841, 
851, 861, 871, 881, 891, 901, 911, 921, 931, 941, 951, 961, 971, 
981), auto_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), double_trig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hypopnea = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -98L)))
```

Select all lists in `df` that contain `auto-trig`

```
df2<- lapply(df, function(x) x[,grepl("auto_trig", colnames(x))])
```

Select all lists in `df1` that contain `auto-trig`

```
df3<- lapply(df1, function(x) x[,grepl("auto_trig", colnames(x))])
```

Make data frames same length

```
df4<- sapply(df2, "length<-", max(lengths(df3)))
df5<- sapply(df3, "length<-", max(lengths(df3)))
```

My desired output is to create one (very) long, end to end vector for each `auto_trig` event that can then be used to calculate a Cohen's kappa.

I would therefore like to replace all `NULL` and `NA` data with `0`.  Then pivot all the data from the list `df4` into 1 vector and repeat for `df5` into a separate vector.

I would then aim to calculate `Cohen.kappa` using the following:

```
auto_trig<- cohen.kappa(x=cbind(df4,df5))
```

Comment: Using your data, you cannot `cbind` the two as they are of different lengths. `bind_rows(df) %>% select(auto_trig)` should give you the longer version of `df4`